# Could not resolve dependencies for project org.openapitools:openapi-generator-online:jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am traying to run **mvn build package** command for my spring boot project but it is giving error

**I tried**

1)maven update project
2)mvn -u clean install

still not working please help I am new at spring boot

**Error**

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project openapi-generator-online:
> Could not resolve dependencies for project
> org.openapitools:openapi-generator-online:jar:6.3.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed
> to collect dependencies at
> org.openapitools:openapi-generator:jar:6.3.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read
> artifact descriptor for
> org.openapitools:openapi-generator:jar:6.3.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not
> transfer artifact
> org.openapitools:openapi-generator:pom:6.3.0-SNAPSHOT from/to
> sonatype-snapshots
> (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): Transfer
> failed for
> https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/openapitools/openapi-generator/6.3.0-SNAPSHOT/openapi-generator-6.3.0-SNAPSHOT.pom:
> PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-project</artifactId>
        <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
        <version>6.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
        <relativePath>../..</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-online</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>openapi-generator-online</name>
    <properties>
        <spring-boot.version>2.7.5</spring-boot.version>
        <springfox-version>3.0.0</springfox-version>
        <sonar.exclusions>**/org/openapitools/codegen/online/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <finalName>openapi-generator-online</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>${project.parent.basedir}${file.separator}google_checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>static-analysis</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeFilterFile>${project.parent.basedir}${file.separator}spotbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>se.bjurr.violations</groupId>
                        <artifactId>violations-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Should be decreased regularly down to 0 as issues are fixed. -->
                            <maxViolations>3</maxViolations>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--SpringFox dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bean Validation API support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: There is a release 6.3.0 of the openapi-maven-plugin etc. but I don't understand why you use the openap-generator-project as parent and more strange as a `SNAPSHOT` does not makes sense to me... ... ??? Furthermore I strongly recommend to use JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5) since 2.6.X?? it's the default... also the PKIX errors looks like you are using an old JDK version... JDK11+ is recommended....

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

The first issue is that your pom parent should not be openapi-generator-project:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-project</artifactId>
    <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
    <version>6.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
    <relativePath>../..</relativePath>
</parent>
```

It should be spring-boot:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

The second issue: "PKIX path building failed" is happening because the repo location  https://oss.sonatype.org for openapi-generator-6.3.0-SNAPSHOT.pom does not have a certificate signed by a CA in your CACERTS.

But if you change the parent & don't reference a SHAPSHOT in your openapi & openapi maven plugin dependencies (both missing in your pom) then it will fetch from the more usual https://repo1.maven.org.

Answer (score 0):

I was running child pom.xml for building. build with parent pom.xml solved my problem